# Uploaded Crashlytics dSYM version unknown

Tags: swift, xcode, crashlytics

New project in XCode, added Firebase iOS library following the [Get Started documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios) Also followed the provided tutorial for setting up XCode to automatically upload dSYM files and finally forced a Test crash.

Here is the Xcode log output after crash and restarting app:

```
10.17.0 - [FirebaseSessions][I-SES000000] Version 10.17.0. Expecting subscriptions from: [Crashlytics]
[Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 10.17.0
10.17.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics] Running on iPhone14,7, 17.3.0 (21D50)
10.17.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Registering Sessions SDK subscription for session data
10.17.0 - [FirebaseSessions][I-SES000000] Registering Sessions SDK subscriber with name: Crashlytics, data collection enabled: true
10.17.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Session ID changed: 81ba754854054cc39c4fe8595a22f92b
10.17.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Root: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/60EC98D8-4998-4D92-B346-C29046E57EF5/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.package.name
10.17.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports:Event] Firebase Analytics SDK not detected. Crash-free statistics and breadcrumbs will not be reported
10.17.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Automatic data collection is enabled.
10.17.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Unsent reports will be uploaded at startup
10.17.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Packaged report with id '59378ba00fcc4bcd904a3d6631a8c1ed' for submission
10.17.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Submitting report async
10.17.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Completed report submission with id: 59378ba00fcc4bcd904a3d6631a8c1ed
```

In Crashlytics console I can read the following:
[image]

After some time, crashes started to appear with dSYM file status: uploaded. But now the App version is "Unknown".. whats going on? There's little or none documentation about this particular situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as expected. When there is a crash before the dSYMs get uploaded, the crash will have:

- The UUID
- And the version and build number

In this scenario, the dSYMs tab will have this info. If more crashes happen, the event count will keep increasing.

Once the respective dSYMs are uploaded and processed, crashes will be symbolicated and the dSYMs tab will stop updating the info from that particular dSYM.

But, when you upload dSYMs to Crashlytics before there are any crashes, the dSYMs gets processed and the dSYMs tab will also stop updating the info related to that UUID. The dSYMs don't have the version and build number and this is why it will remain as "unknown".

If you are seeing crashes from a particular version/build number in the dashboard, that means that everything has been uploaded correctly.